# Go Geometry question 1273 proof/ solution - Show angle bisector and polar line bisect another angle

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

I am currently learning proofs related to geometry, which is why I have been looking at this [problem](https://gogeometry.blogspot.com/2016/10/geometry-problem-1273-circle-tangent.html) (I hope it is okay to link to external websites). Here is the problem: Given a point $A$ outside of a circle. Two tangents go through the point $A$ and touch the circle at $B$ and $C$ respectively. The center of the line $BC$ is $M$. Given a secant through $A$ which crosses the circle at $D$ and crosses $BC$ at $E$, show that $\angle BDM=\angle EDC$.

Users have posted solutions but they seem rather incomplete to me because I can't follow those solutions posted by other users.
So I wanted to show my idea/ approach:

[image]

It suffices to show that the arc $BG$ and $CF$ are equal in length. That can be shown by showing that $\angle AMD=\angle HMF$. So $AH$ has to be an external angle bisector of $\angle DMF$. Of course $AH$ is the (internal) angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ because $M$ lies in the middle of $BC$. Unfortunaletly that's were I can't make any meaningful progress because I don't know to show how that $\angle AMD=\angle HMF$ is true.
Tips and help would be appreciated!

Comment: OP, it is requested that you type out the problem on this site itself. This increases convenience, and, more importantly, it also allows the problem to be searchable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't know...
But it is fixed now

Comment: The problem seems fairly simple via a coordinate geometry approach. How is it fixed? You haven't typed it out.

Comment: I have indeed typed the problem out: "Here is the problem: Given a point $A$ outside of a circle. Two tangents go through the point $A$ and touch the circle at $B$ and $C$ respectively. The center of the line $BC$ is $M$. Given a secant through $A$ which crosses the circle at $D$ and crosses $BC$ at $E$, show that $\angle BDM=\angle EDC$". You can see it at the top of the post.

Or do you mean something different?

Answer (score 1):

$AO$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.

$\triangle ABM\sim \triangle AOB$ and thereafter $AM\cdot AO=AB^{2}$. Also since $AD\cdot AL=AB^{2}$,  $AD\cdot AL=AM\cdot AO$ and thereafter quadrilateral $LOMD$ is cyclic.

Now by simple angle chasing it will follow that $\angle DMC=\angle DBL$ and thereafter $\triangle BDL\sim \triangle MDC$ and hence $\angle BDL=\angle MDC$.